# SQL Server : how to get latest rows with some conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to data transformation using SQL. I'm struggling getting latest data with stage = draft or finish. Could anyone give me some advice?

From this:

```
Name | Stage   | UpdateDate |
-----+---------+------------+
a    | draft   | 8/17/2014  |
a    | draft   | 8/25/2014  |
a    | finish  | 8/25/2014  |
b    | draft   | 2/14/2015  |
b    | draft   | 2/15/2015  |
b    | draft   | 2/16/2015  |
```

To this:

```
Name | Stage   | UpdateDate |
-----+---------+------------+
a    | draft   | 8/25/2014  |
a    | finish  | 8/25/2014  |
b    | draft   | 2/16/2015  |
```

Comment: . . Your question is unclear.  Do you want one row per `name`/`stage` with the latest date?  Or, do you want all rows with the latest date for a `name`?

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that you want the latest row for each name/draft pair (that is how I read the question):

A simple method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.updatedate = (select max(t2.updatedate)
                      from t t2
                      where t2.name = t.name and t2.stage = t.stage
                     );
```

Another good method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name, stage order by updatedate desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you really want all rows with the latest date overall for the name, then you can tweak these.  For instance:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, rank() over (partition by name order by updatedate desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Isn't this just `select name, stage, max(UpdateDate) from t group by name, stage`?

Comment: @LoztInSpace . . . Yes . . . unless the OP has extra columns that are not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT *
FROM tblFoo
WHERE [UpdateDate] in (SELECT MAX(UpdateDate)
                FROM tblFoo
                Group by [Name], [Stage])
```

This is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 with ties 
   *
from 
    YourTable
order by 
    row_number() over(partition by Name, Stage order by UpdateDate desc)
```

**UPDATE** (full answer):

```
declare @Table table (
    [Name]      char(1)     not null,
    Stage       varchar(6)  not null,
    UpdateDate  date        not null
);

insert into @Table
values 
( 'a', 'draft'  , '2014-8-17'  ),
( 'a', 'draft'  , '2014-8-25'  ),
( 'a', 'finish' , '2014-8-25'  ),
( 'b', 'draft'  , '2015-2-14'  ),
( 'b', 'draft'  , '2015-2-15'  ),
( 'b', 'draft'  , '2015-2-16'  );


select top 1 with ties 
   [Name],
   Stage,
   UpdateDate = convert(varchar(10), UpdateDate, 101)
from 
    @Table
order by 
    row_number() over(partition by Name, Stage order by UpdateDate desc);
```

The same in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/09708/1)

TOP 1 works with WITH TIES here. WITH TIES means that when ORDER BY = 1, then SELECT takes this record (because of TOP 1) and all others that have ORDER BY = 1 (because of WITH TIES).

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.